# Which is the vanilla javascript equivalent for .not() of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a loop which adds a class to a list. I wish this class to be added on all the elements except the element which is being clicked. I found the following on the internet:

```
$('.elements').click(function(){
     $('.elements').not(this).each(function(){
         // do something
     });
})
```

Is there an equivalent to vanilla javascript? I cannot find the conversion from [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: There isn't one afaik, you'd have to build your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vanilla version of the full code you posted would be something like this. Quite verbose TBH without having the helper to add a click listener to each el.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.elements');
[].forEach.call(els, function(el, i, els) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        [].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
            if(el !== this) {
                // do something
            }
        }, this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The closest equivalent is probably [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which allows you to test each element of an array with a function:

```
var elementToExclude = something;
arrayOfElements.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem !== elementToExclude;
}).forEach(doSomething);
```

Comment: Utterly nitpicking here, but worth pointing out that this won't work with a NodeList ( need to use `[].filter.call(arrayOfElements, function(elem){})` ). I know you said `arrayOfElements`, just thought it was worth pointing out to others reading it

Comment: @benhowdle89 - true, good point. I was more thinking of the array you'd end up with if given the OPs jQuery collection and then called `.get()` on it.

Comment: Aha, fair enough. I just assumed because OP was asking for a non-jQuery solution, it all needed to be non-jQuery. Like I said, really nitpicking here!

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.filter.call(nodeList, function() {})` to work with NodeList elements

Answer (score 1):

You should analyze [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click). Watch on the target and currentTarget properties.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErBlack/artq1t89/)

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
        do something
    } else {
        don't do something
    }
});
```