# javascript - last image clicked bring to front

Tags: javascript, html, image, click, draggable

I'm trying to make a really simple website in javascript.
I want the website to have a stack of images that you can drag.
So far I managed to do it. But now I want to always bring to front the last clicked image.
How can I do this ? Thanks !

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.4.0/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style>

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      var img1 = new Konva.Image({
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        width: 400,
        height: 566,
        
        draggable: true,
      });
      layer.add(img1);

      var img2 = new Konva.Image({
        x: 100,
        y: 20,
        width: 400,
        height: 566,
        draggable: true,
        
      });
      layer.add(img2);

      var imageObj1 = new Image();
      imageObj1.onload = function () {
        img1.image(imageObj1);
      };
      imageObj1.src = 'imgs/img1.jpg';

      var imageObj2 = new Image();
      imageObj2.onload = function () {
        img2.image(imageObj2);
      };
      imageObj2.src = 'imgs/img2.jpg';

      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen this code on another post, but I don't know how to make it work ..

```
$("img.myclass").click(function() {
     $("img.myclass").not(this).css("z-index", 0);
     $(this).css("z-index", 100);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/5v8pm0eL/1/)? That would be one way of converting your jQuery code to plain Javascript. Please note, the example I've given is simplified, and does not use Konva. There are other ways of handling the `.not()` function in your example, and you can read about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012799/). Also, instead of changing the inline CSS (z-index), you could have it all in a class, and just keep adding / removing that class as you go (`.toggle()` is also an option when dealing with classes).

Answer (score 2):

The "code on another post" is written in [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) wich is an javascript library and need to be added to your page as you do with *konva*.
Konva is a tool that draw an [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).
You can change [zIndex](https://konvajs.org/docs/groups_and_layers/zIndex.html) (property that will change order of your stack) when you click on image.
For example:

```
img1.zIndex(0);
img2.zIndex(1); // will set img2 higher
```

If image didn't have *zIndex()* function you can try to wrap it to a *group*.

```
const group1 = new Konva.Group();

group1.add(img1);
group1.zIndex(0);
```

#### Edit:

Increase zIndex on click.

```
let zIndex = 0;

img.onclick = function () {
   zIndex += 1;
   img.zIndex(zIndex);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! But how can I have a dynamic change of the zIndex of a image  when I click on it ? I'm sorry, I'm really new to Javascript, and don't understand everything well..

Comment: That's okay.You can add on click event to images and change there zIndex. For example you can store last known zIndex, and when you click increase zIndex and set it for clicked image. I will edit answer